# How can I change an existing type from "bigint" to "bigserial"?

Tags: postgresql, identity, postgresql-10

I have a PostgreSQL table with the following structure:

[image]

I simply need to change the `TYPE` of `prove_identity_id` from `bigint` to `bigserial`.  I read the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) but wasn't able to understand how to legally achieve the change without the following error: `PostgreSQL said: type "bigserial" does not exist`

`PostgreSQL 10.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76), 64-bit`

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: FYI, the `SERIAL` pseudo-types are now supplanted by [identity columns](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/) per the SQL standard.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[**`bigserial`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) is a pseudo-type, a notational convenience that is resolved to type `bigint` internally - plus a sequence, a column default, a dependency and an ownership.

Basic commands to convert an existing `bigint` column with existing rows to a `bigserial`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tbl_tbl_id_seq;
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN tbl_id SET DEFAULT nextval('tbl_tbl_id_seq');
ALTER SEQUENCE tbl_tbl_id_seq OWNED BY tbl.tbl_id;
SELECT setval('tbl_tbl_id_seq', COALESCE(max(tbl_id), 1)) FROM tbl;
```

`setval()` to get the `SEQUENCE` in sync with the currently highest id.  Replace `tbl` with your table name (`prove_identity` ?).

However, it looks like you have a proper `bigserial` column already. This might all be a misunderstanding, then.

See:

- [Creating a PostgreSQL sequence to a field (which is not the ID of the record)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659884/939860)

Related:

- [How to convert primary key from integer to serial?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27309311/939860)
- [Safely and cleanly rename tables that use serial primary key columns in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14651788/939860)

In Postgres 10 or later, consider an **`IDENTITY`** column instead. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860)

Comment: Thank you.  Your query ran but the type is still showing as bigint but I guess that's ok after reading some of your answers.  I'll try to write my data and see if it works.

Comment: @DaveChambers: Some clients (like pgAdmin) display the pseudo-types `serial` / `bigserial`, others (like yours? you should declare your client) display the actual data type. It's a purely a matter of *representation*.

Comment: You can't use setval to set the sequence to zero. So where you call setval above, please use coalesce with a default of 1, i.e. `SELECT setval('tbl_tbl_id_seq', COALESCE(max(tbl_id), 1)) FROM tbl;`

Comment: @balrob: Thanks, fixed. Aside: You *can* set a sequence to 0, if it was created with `MINVALUE` accordingly. But not with default `MINVALUE` 1.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using PostgreSQL 10, you should be using the [`IDENTITY PROPERTY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-altertable.html) on the bigint column, and not using the `serial` or `bigserial` macros at all - it's Pg specific syntax that is difficult to understand, and in the event of permission modification: easy to mess up.

```
ALTER TABLE provide_identity
  ALTER COLUMN prove_identity_id
  ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT
  AS IDENTITY;
```

But instead of messing with that directly, I'd suggest backing up the database and running this script from the [2nd quadrant blog](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/). Run it like this,

```
SELECT upgrade_serial_to_identity('public.prove_identity', 'prove_identity_id');
```