# postgres: Upgraded RDS Postgres from 9.4 - 9.6, id fields went from SERIAL to INT

Tags: postgresql

So, on my RDS postgres, that is currently running as a DMS CDC from our previous DB, our ID fields lost the serial type, and it got moved to INT without a NEXTVAL. So, using the example of our table public.pageviews, I tried

```
ALTER TABLE public.pageviews ALTER COLUMN id TYPE SERIAL;
```

and it is giving me that SERIAL is not a valid data type.

When I run

```
ALTER TABLE public.pageviews ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('pageviews_id_seq');
```

I am getting the following:

> ERROR:  null value in column "c_key" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 2018-01-03 14:17:28.952708,
>   master, 1528336, ALTER TABLE, 0, , public, ALTER TABLE
>   public.pageviews ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval...). CONTEXT: 
>   SQL statement "insert into public.awsdms_ddl_audit
>         values
>         (
>         default,current_timestamp,current_user,cast(TXID_CURRENT()as varchar(16)),tg_tag,0,'',current_schema,_qry
>         )" PL/pgSQL function awsdms_intercept_ddl() line 6 at SQL statement
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: null value in column "c_key" violates not-null constraint SQL
>   state: 23502 Detail: Failing row contains (null, 2018-01-03
>   14:17:28.952708, master, 1528336, ALTER TABLE, 0, , public, ALTER
>   TABLE public.pageviews ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval...).
>   Context: SQL statement "insert into public.awsdms_ddl_audit
>         values
>         (
>         default,current_timestamp,current_user,cast(TXID_CURRENT()as varchar(16)),tg_tag,0,'',current_schema,_qry
>         )" PL/pgSQL function awsdms_intercept_ddl() line 6 at SQL statement

On that, I am not a PG DBA by trade (MSSQL that got lucked into this job) so I am not familiar enough with how to really make my way around things, on pgadmin, I have tried to set the default value for ID to a nextval, but I am not getting anywhere with that.

I'm on windows and have really no experience with psql commands (learning them, but the curve is steep)

Comment: Have a look at the answer of this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194383/how-can-i-change-an-existing-type-from-bigint-to-bigserial

Comment: Question and (accepted) answer over on Stackoverflow: [Changing primary key int type to serial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23578427/1820861).

Comment: @hot2use - when I try to do that, I get that error that I posted in the main question.

Comment: @McNets - When I try to do this I get the error listed.

Comment: Because a SERIAL, in fact, is defined as INT NOT NULL and it seems that your table has some null values.

Comment: Reviewed the data, there are no nulls in the ID field.

Comment: That `c_key` column is not in `pageviews`, right?  It seems the error is coming from a DDL trigger defined by Database Migration Service.  I think you have to remove DMS (read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.CleanUp), and then set it up again if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

While it appears that DMS supports migrating the SERIAL datatype, DMS doesn't support migrating default values like your `SET DEFAULT nextval('pageviews_id_seq')`

If you are running ongoing replication, then all the data in the read replica target is created in the source database, that is where the nextval from that sequence will be applied.

It kind of makes sense, because DMS is trying to explicity insert a value into that `id` column, and you shouldn't explicitly set a column that is supposed to have its value generated by a sequence.

If you're using DMS to migrate a database with the intention to switch off the old one then you'll have to

- switch off DMS, then on the new database:
- create the sequence object `pageviews_id_seq`, setting the sequence to start at a value higher than the max id in the table, so it's nextval doesn't collide with an existing id
- alter the column to apply the `SET DEFAULT nextval('pageviews_id_seq')`

---

In your specific case, there is a trigger on the source database (see link below to docs) which looks like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION <objects_schema>.awsdms_intercept_ddl()
  RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
  AS $$
  declare _qry text;
BEGIN
  if (tg_tag='CREATE TABLE' or tg_tag='ALTER TABLE' or tg_tag='DROP TABLE') then
         SELECT current_query() into _qry;
         insert into <objects_schema>.awsdms_ddl_audit
         values
         (
         default,current_timestamp,current_user,cast(TXID_CURRENT()as varchar(16)),tg_tag,0,'',current_schema,_qry
         );
         delete from <objects_schema>.awsdms_ddl_audit;
end if;
END;
$$;
```

It is trying to insert the default value for the first column in the table `awsdms_ddl_audit`.

According to the docs the table should look like this

```
create table <objects_schema>.awsdms_ddl_audit
(
  c_key    bigserial primary key,
  c_time   timestamp,    -- Informational
  c_user   varchar(64),  -- Informational: current_user
  c_txn    varchar(16),  -- Informational: current transaction
  c_tag    varchar(24),  -- Either 'CREATE TABLE' or 'ALTER TABLE' or 'DROP TABLE'
  c_oid    integer,      -- For future use - TG_OBJECTID
  c_name   varchar(64),  -- For future use - TG_OBJECTNAME
  c_schema varchar(64),  -- For future use - TG_SCHEMANAME. For now - holds current_schema
  c_ddlqry  text         -- The DDL query associated with the current DDL event
)
```

- `ckey` is supposed to be a `bigserial`, so this should be inserting an incremented bigint automatically for you ( similar to `IDENTITY` on MSSQL ). The error says that it is failing when trying to insert a NULL, so can you check the datatype for that `c_key` column, I suspect in your DB the datatype isn't right.

!! Note that in the docs it says you need to do these thing *in order* 
1. create the `aws_ddl_audit` table
2. create the trigger function
3. attatch the trigger to the ddl_command_end then execute it

The trigger monitors all `create` , `update` and `drop` table statements, which would include creating the `aws_ddl_audit` table if you create the table *after* the trigger.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.Limitations